# Android emulator restart fails

Tags: android-emulator, hyper-v, hypervisor, ms-android-emulator

I have Android emulator installed using Visual Studio 2019 and enabled hyper-v and hypervisor platform using windows features.

I created new device using "Android Device Manager" tool and when I start it, it works perfectly. But if I close it and start again it opens and screen displays last state from last session. Then nothing happens, it never loads. If I drop device system settings to default state and start again, it works but I don't want to do that every time, plus I want to be able to store app data between sessions.

So How do I make it work?

Or how do I make it stop trying to save state, always start cold?

I have Windows 10, Android emulator version 28.0.25, SDK tools 26.1.1, SDK platform tools 28.0.2.

config.ini for my device:

```
disk.dataPartition.size=800M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=emulated
hw.dPad=no
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=320
hw.lcd.height=720
hw.lcd.width=1280
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.ramSize=1024
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
sdcard.size=100M
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=1280x720
vm.heapSize=256
hw.device.hash2=MD5:e6de262aae26d1ce2c8a8b656265afbc
hw.device.name=4.7in WXGA
hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
showDeviceFrame=no
tag.id=google_apis
tag.display=Google APIs
PlayStore.enabled=false
abi.type=x86
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
avd.ini.displayname=720x1280_A9.0
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86\
AvdId=720x1280_a9_0
```

Some logs from Android Device Monitor tool:

```
E/SurfaceFlinger(1732): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
E/LocalDisplayAdapter(6626): Default and active color mode is no longer available! Reverting to first available mode.
E/LightsService(6626): Unable to get ILight interface.
E/Parcel(6626): Class not found when unmarshalling: android.content.pm.PackageParser$SigningDetail?
E/Parcel(6626): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.pm.PackageParser$SigningDetail?
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2803)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2757)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser$Package.<init>(PackageParser.java:6821)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.fromCacheEntryStatic(PackageParser.java:1071)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.fromCacheEntry(PackageParser.java:1058)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.getCachedResult(PackageParser.java:1152)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:1013)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.server.pm.ParallelPackageParser.parsePackage(ParallelPackageParser.java:138)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.server.pm.ParallelPackageParser.lambda$submit$0(ParallelPackageParser.java:117)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.server.pm.-$$Lambda$ParallelPackageParser$FTtinPrp068lVeI7K6bC1tNE3iM.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.internal.util.ConcurrentUtils$1$1.run(ConcurrentUtils.java:62)
E/Parcel(6626): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.pm.PackageParser$SigningDetail?
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1346)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1406)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/Parcel(6626):     ... 17 more
E/Parcel(6626): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
E/Parcel(6626): Class not found when unmarshalling: android.content.pm.PackageParser$Signing???????
E/Parcel(6626): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.pm.PackageParser$Signing???????
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2803)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2757)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser$Package.<init>(PackageParser.java:6821)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.fromCacheEntryStatic(PackageParser.java:1071)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.fromCacheEnpm.PackaageParser.java:1058)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.getCachedResult(PackageParser.java:1152)
E/Parcel(6626):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:1013)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.server.pm.ParallelPackageParser.parsePackage(ParallelPackageParser.java:138)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.server.pm.ParallelPackageParser.lambda$submit$0(ParallelPackageParser.java:117)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.server.pm.-$$Lambda$ParallelPackageParser$FTtinPrp068lVeI7K6bC1tNE3iM.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/Parcel(6626):     at com.android.internal.util.ConcurrentUtils$1$1.run(ConcurrentUtils.java:62)
E/Parcel(6626): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.pm.PackageParser$Signing???????
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1346)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1406)
E/Parcel(6626):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/Parcel(6626):     ... 17 more
E/Parcel(6626): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
E/PackageManager(6626): Adding duplicate user id: 10008 name=com.google.android.gms
```

Then it's just non-verbal codes with file paths and prefix of

> A/system_server(6626): file_utils.cc:113]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting called Quickboot which you can disable for each AVD individually, it will do a cold boot every time then.

But this is not the best solution, I would like Quickboot to actually work.

[image]

Ref https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#quickboot